# VideoCapture::read always returns false

Tags: c++, opencv, video-capture, osx-elcapitan

I'm running OS X El Capitan and trying to use OpenCV VideoCapture to read an .avi file.  I've tried it on both opencv 2.4.1 and 3, both of which have the same outcome.

```
cv::VideoCapture capture("filename.avi");
cv::Mat currentFrame, prevFrame;
bool capPrevSuccess = capture.read(prevFrame);
bool capCurrSuccess = capture.read(currentFrame);
```

I've verified that the filename.avi is in the current working directory and I don't see any errors in the console.

I'm beginning to wonder if it's something with my machine.  I have a similar problem running VideoReader in MATLAB on the same machine.  I believe MATLAB uses OpenCV VideoReader as well, perhaps they're connected.

> Error using VideoReader/init (line 619) Failed to initialize internal
>   resources.
>
> Error in VideoReader (line 172)
>               obj.init(fileName);

EDIT: Looks like this has something to do with the video files I'm using.  I downloaded an mp4 video, and had no trouble with it.  Unfortunately I need to use the video files I'm using (all .avi), yet they all seem to not work with VideoCapture.

Comment: what codecs are used in your avi files? maybe open them in virtualDub and convert to a different codec

Comment: Your code works well for me at my machine. I used as codes h264, which is always a code choice with opencv

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.  I'm not sure which codecs the avi uses internally, though I used a third party mp4 converter (setting the output codec to h.264) and it works fine.  Looking at the ffmpeg -i output, the first shows xvid and the second shows mp4v.  before convert:  Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg4 (Simple Profile) (XVID / 0x44495658), yuv420p.  after convert: Stream #0:0(und): Video: mpeg4 (Simple Profile) (mp4v / 0x7634706D), yuv420p.  I'm guessing xvid isn't an producing h.264 stream, while mp4v does.